# amazon linux installation of rpy2 fails

Tags: redhat, installation, amazon-ami, pip

the installation of rpy2 an amazon linux via

```
sudo pip-2.7 install rpy2
```

fails with

```
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:58:0:
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8:15: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Installation by compilation of the source fails in the same manner. `sudo python2.7 setup.py install`

complete log at:
https://gist.github.com/4362543

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to install the R-development files with:

```
sudo yum -y install R-devel
```